# Controller not loading when using jQuery.append

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently using jQuery to display modal windows, the function basically builds some HTML and then does `$('#myElement').append(modalHtml);`

Inside that modal HTML I have `<div ng-controller="MyController">...</div>` however when the modal is displayed the controller doesn't seem to get initialized. Is this because it's being added to the DOM outside of angular's scope? If so is there anyway when I run that code I could notify angular to look out for changes?

The breakdown of how it is at the moment is Angular runs `loadModal()` through an `ng-click` on an element. `loadModal()` calls `modal()`, and `modal()` builds the html and adds it to the DOM. Modal is in a script of just standalone helper functions.

Comment: It's not ideal to mix jQuery and AngularJS like that. Could you not create a 'modalHtml' directive element?

Comment: I think I might have to, all the helper functions where made by someone else before I started this project.

Comment: if you are dynamically inserting HTML into angular's scope (which you shouldn't using jQuery; ng-include would be better), you need to manually bootstrap your application (you have to manually start it, rather than automatically) See here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Comment: A good alternative to jQuery for modals is AngularUI or AngularStrap

Comment: Unfortunately not, I reworked my project so I didn't need this anymore, but tasseKATT's answer looks like it might work, I've not tried it yet though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modal controller won't be called because you're not parsing or compiling the appended DOM code with Angular. Hence, Angular will not 'notice' this change and as a result it will not run any controllers or directives in the added DOM. The best way to solve this kind of problems is by adding a custom directive.

As you're trying to make a modal work, you could also take a look at existing modal adaptations for Angular, such as the one in [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/).